# Backbone: Best Way to Convert Model to Different Model Class

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've got a couple of Backbone models:

```
var MainThing = Backbone.Model(/* some methods */);

var CustomerFacingThing = MainThing.extend(/* overrides of those methods */);
```

At several places in my code I have a `MainThing` instance, but I want to convert it in to a `CustomerFacingThing` so that I can pass it to some code my customer-written code:

```
var mainThing = new MainThing();
customerFunction(mainThing.convertToCustomerFacingThing());
```

My question is, what's the best way to do that?  One way I can think of is to just change the prototype:

```
mainThing.prototype = CustomerFacingThing.prototype;
```

but that wouldn't change the "hidden prototype", so I'm not sure that would work (eg. I'm not sure`mainThing instanceof CustomerFacingThing` would be `true`).

I could also copy over the attributes and events on to a new `CustomerFacingThing` instance:

```
var customerFacingVersion = new CustomerFacingThing();
customerFacingVersion.attributes = mainThing.attributes;
customerFacingVersion.events = mainThing.events;
```

but since the events are already bound at that point I'm not sure that would work either.  Also, `mainThing` could have non-attribute properties, so really I'd have to do:

```
_(mainThing).each(function(value, key) {
    customerFacingThing[key] = value;
});
```

but that would overwrite customer facing methods on the instance with the main versions of those methods.

So, can anyone explain the best way to change the class of a Backbone.Model instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a CustomerFacingThing constructor - and passing the MainThing in as a parameter.
Since Backbone.Models store their data in attributes, the code below should be the same:

```
var mainThing = new MainThing();
var customerThing = new CustomerThing();
mainThing.get('propertyName') == customerThing.get('propertyName');
```

You can then use the following code in your constructor:
Note this is TypeScript syntax.

```
class ListItem extends Backbone.Model implements IListItem {
    get Id(): number { return this.get('Id'); }
    set Id(value: number) { this.set('Id', value); }
    set Name(value: string) { this.set('Name', value); }
    get Name(): string { return this.get('Name'); }

    constructor(input: IListItem) {
        super();
        for (var key in input) {
            if (key) {
                this[key] = input[key];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Details of this technique can be found here : http://blorkfish.wordpress.com/2013/03/20/typescript-strongly-typed-backbone-models/